# Collapse no bootstrap 4

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Queria que quando clicasse em um dos menus collapse os outros ocultassem e não estou conseguindo, estou utilizando o seguinte código em jquery, eu não sei se está certo:

```
$( ".card" ).on( "click", "#menu_arrow", function() {        
    $( "div[class|='collapse']" ).removeClass('show');
});
```

Os menus estão em um laço php que exibi os usuários juntamente com esse menuzinho do lado do nome:

```
<div class="right-col col-lg-4 align-self-center align-items-center">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="menu_arrow" href="#collapse<?php echo $matricula['id']; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $matricula['id']; ?>">Menu de opções <i class="fa fa-caret-down" id="caret2" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <div id="collapse<?php echo $matricula['id']; ?>" class="collapse hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $matricula['id']; ?>">
        <div class="opt"><a href="<?php echo $url_base . "/painel/editar_usuarios.php?id=" . $matricula['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Editar cadastro</a></div>
        <div class="opt"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Editar boletim</a></div>
        <div class="opt"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> Imprimir histórico</a></div>
        <div class="opt"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> Imprimir ficha</a></div>
        <div class="opt"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i> Portifólio</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que você esconda o menu ao clicar em alguma opção você pode usar o `collapse("hide")`, você deve aplicar a ação de `click` em todas tags `<a>` que estão dentro das `divs` com a classe `collapse`.

Sua função javascript ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
 $(".collapse a").click(function() {
       $(this).closest(".collapse").collapse("hide");
 });
```

Lembrando que fiz o uso de `$(this).closest(".collapse")` porquê me parece que você está gerando as divs com o collapse dentro de um for e precisava ser genérico, caso contrario bastaria fazer a chamada pelo `id` do elemento.

Comment: Sua resposta não resolveu meu problema, mas me ajudou a resolver, então obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando um tipo de seletor do jquery, para selecionar todos os elementos com a classe "menu_arrow_container" que criei para identificar onde o menu fica.

```
$(".menu_container a").click(function() {
   $('div[class*="menu_arrow_container"]').closest(".collapse").collapse("hide");
});
```